# LEFT JOIN tables but exclude if conditions don't match

Tags: mysql

I have dynamic conditions. Sometimes there are conditions and sometimes not. I want to get all results from the left but exclude rows that do not match conditions. Is there any way I can achieve this? With what I have it always gets all rows from the left. If I use inner join it won't get the records from the base table if they can't join. I need to be able to get all records from the anime table, however if there is a condition set, then only get the records that match the conditions.

```
SELECT anime.id, anime.title, IF(english IS NULL or english = '', anime.title, english) as english, anime.slug
FROM anime
LEFT JOIN genres g ON g.anime_id = anime.id
LEFT JOIN episodes e ON e.anime_id = anime.id
LEFT JOIN videos v on v.episode_id = e.id
$conds
GROUP BY anime.id
ORDER BY $order
LIMIT $limit
```

$conds, $order, and $limit is the dynamically generated with php.

an example for a condition is

```
WHERE anime.status = 'completed' AND v.type = 'subbed'
```

The problem here is if I use left join the condition for v.type is completely ignored and it gets all records from the anime table.

Doing a left join will get all rows from the anime table regardless. But I want to not get all rows if there is a condition and only the rows that match the condition. But if there is no conditions then get all rows anyways.

If I use INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN, if an anime has no episodes or videos it won't get them, but I NEED to get them.

Comment: Where is the problem? If `$conds` is set, I suppose as `WHERE x='y'`, just the rows which fits to this condition/s are selected.

Comment: Without seeing what might be in $cond, there's no way to answer your question. If there are conditions on the anime table, that might exclude rows.

Comment: added an example

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar trouble, you need to use EXISTS, as the following example:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table_1 t1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT t2.* FROM table2 t2
WHERE t1.id=t2.t1_id AND t2.some_field='some value')
```

So your query should look like this:

```
SELECT anime.id, anime.title, IF(english IS NULL or english = '', anime.title, english) as english, anime.slug
FROM anime
LEFT JOIN genres g ON g.anime_id = anime.id
LEFT JOIN episodes e ON e.anime_id = anime.id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT v.* FROM videos v WHERE v.episode_id = e.id AND v.type = 'subbed')
AND anime.status = 'completed'
GROUP BY anime.id
ORDER BY $order
LIMIT $limit
```

i know that your question is old, but i submit this for anyone with a similar problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need the following

```
$query_with_condition = "SELECT ...
FROM anime
LEFT JOIN genres g ON g.anime_id = anime.id
LEFT JOIN episodes e ON e.anime_id = anime.id
LEFT JOIN videos v on v.episode_id = e.id
$conds
GROUP BY anime.id
ORDER BY $order
LIMIT $limit";

$query_without_condition = "SELECT ...
FROM anime
LEFT JOIN genres g ON g.anime_id = anime.id
LEFT JOIN episodes e ON e.anime_id = anime.id
LEFT JOIN videos v on v.episode_id = e.id
GROUP BY anime.id
ORDER BY $order
LIMIT $limit";

$result = mysql_query($query_with_condition, $conn);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

// if the query with conditions doesn't return any rows
if(!$num_rows){
  // then we use the second query where no conditions
  $result = mysql_query($query_without_condition, $conn);
}

// use $result
```

---

I don't know but maybe you need the following

```
WHERE anime.status = 'completed' AND IFNULL(v.type,'subbed') = 'subbed'
```

It also returns row from the left-table if this row haven't link with a video.

If I'm mistaken please, add test data for tables `anime` and `videos`.
And show an expected result for this data.

Answer (score 0):

The "generic answer" is if you want the left join to "survive" a where clause condition you must also allow for NULL to be returned by the left join.

```
WHERE anime.status = 'completed' AND (v.type = 'subbed' OR v.type IS NULL)
```

nb: If you use functions to mimic the same effect then you removed access to indexes and that may badly affect query performance.

Comment: I actually want the opposite of that. Doing a left join will get all rows from the anime table regardless. But I want to not get all rows if there is a condition and only the rows that match the condition. But if there is no conditions then get all rows anyways.

Comment: well if you want the opposite, then do what you already have in he question. what happens then is that the left join is overruled by the where clause conditions making it the equivalent of an inner join at that point. If there are no conditions would you not expect everything to be returned?

Comment: That works but if an anime has no episodes or videos, it won't work. I need something magical in between left and inner join.

Comment: @Cc Cc - It's very difficult to understand your question. ) I updated my answer. Maybe it's what you want. )